# PHP - Get multiple values between

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5

I have html templates with contain some function like:

```
<label ng-bind="translate('form.label.email')"></label>
```

The translate() function is used multiple times in a view. I want to extract all the values from the templates. How can i do that?

This example needs to return form.label.email only

Comment: Usw regex. Habe a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Can you help me out? I have no clue how to start. I have a preg_match_all with the pattern $pattern = "#translate(([^<]+)')#"; but i cant get further

Comment: Show your usage, seems close here, https://eval.in/527088.

Answer (score 0):

1. As i mentioned in my comment use a preg_match_all like:

   ```
   preg_match_all("/<label ng-bind=\"translate\('[a-z]+.?[a-z]+.?[a-z]+'\)\"><\/label>/", $input_lines, $output_array);
   ```
2. for each value in the $output_array:
   delete `<label ng-bind="translate('` and delete  `)"></label>` (e.g. with str_replace()
3. Finally you have your values in a array

I create and test regex here: http://www.phpliveregex.com/